# Is there a ?? operator for python

Tags: python

Is there a ?? operator in python like there is in C#?  Which mean if the left side is Null/None then use the right side instead:

```
myVal = myVal ?? 1
```

will return 1 if myVal is Null.  This is covenant for initialization, if this operator does not exist in python, what's the best way to mimic it?

Comment: It's the `or` operator.  `myVal = myVal or 1` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: `or` will work if rejecting any Falsey value is sufficient. If you specifically want to reject only `None`, you need a conditional expression; perhaps with `:=` to reduce duplication.